# Cancelled a git-clone, where are the downloaded files?

Tags: git

I just cancelled a git-clone while it was receiving objects, using ^C on my Mac OSX 10.6.8. Git had already download 1.2GB, according to the "receiving objects" line. I'd like to remove these files, since that's a big chunk of memory, but I can't find them anywhere.

The folder I was cloning them to hadn't been created yet, and there is no obvious .git-*xyz* folder in the parent directory that could hold them.

Any thoughts? Or are they just in some OS-defined temporary folder and will get cleaned up automatically at some point?

Comment: `git-clone` should clean up for you if you give it an interrupt.  Why do you believe they still exist?

Comment: git doesn't use a temporary folder, it copies directly into .git. So if that folder doesn't exist your files are already deleted. (unless you have specified a temp folder yourself) Source: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout-index.html

Comment: Ok, thank you. If one of you wants to make that into an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @EdwardThomson "should clean up for you". How "nice" of it. The cleanup is not a  useful feature. Users could simply add it on top of git themselves while adding a quick re-clone/re-fetch for a sizable target over a network whose speed isn't infinity is impossible. There's a reason most other popular downloading tools (wget, curl, webbrowsers) the files there in order to allow for the download to be continued later.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

as one of the commenters said, for a git clone git://foosite/fooproj, git will create a directory called fooproj/.git and download all the repo files into there.

the second stage of clone is a "checkout" of the origin/master branch usually, but since your ctrl-c was caught by the app, the directories were likely deleted, and no checkout was done.

i.e. if

$ ls -a fooproj

doesn't yield anything, then the files were already deleted.

Comment: My last big clone stored it's temp files in: `.git\objects\pack\tmp_pack_123def`